# How to update value in combo box using combo box text?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

I have a very simple question that i can't seem to find the answer, i have looked up and down in google, msdn with no luck...

it's really simple yet i can't seem to wrap my mind around it.

here goes:

If i'm using simple Drop down style combo box(the one that looks like a listbox with textbox attached on top of the cbobx control) when i want to update one of the value in it, once i start typing in the textbox the selection inside the combo box is gone. Thus i can't update the value inside the combo box.

i know i can use a regular text box to do this, but i'd really like to make this work or i would really loose sleep over this.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt seem very intuative editing the selection in a combobox, but the following should do the trick:

```
 Private cbindex As Integer

 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    cbindex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
 End Sub

 Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.LostFocus
    ComboBox1.Items(cbindex) = ComboBox1.Text
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked, just never knew you could do this part Items(cbindex)

Comment: i've accepted your answer, once again thank you and have a nice one!